# Can svg attribute name be in japanese

Tags: xml, svg

Can any svg node custom **attribute name** (not value) be in japanese?

Also does the xml specs allows the attribute name to be in japanese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most things are allowed, including Japanese. Attribute names may not start with digits or combining characters. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn for more details.